# Alinear items con flex a un contenedor

Tags: css, flexbox

A ver tengo una especie de blog con un prototipo de divs fijos, y quiero que se alineen todos para que así quede un tipo blog con cada entrada de un tamaño y los cuadrados naranjas de publicidad. Alguien sabría como hacerlo? Quería eliminar los espacios señalados con azul para que las imágenes suban

```
<!-- Blog -->
<section id="blog">
    <?php
    $entrada = new Entrada();
    $entrada->get();
    $datos = $entrada->get_rows();
    $tamañoCompleto = count($datos);
    $datos = array_reverse($datos);
    $contador = 1;
    if ($datos) { ?>
        <div class="contenedor-blog">
            <?php if (!isset($_GET['entrada'])) { ?>
                <!--  Contenedor miniaturas -->
                <div class="contenedor-miniaturas">
                    <?php foreach ($datos as $key => $entrada) {
                        if ($contador == 2 || $contador == 7) { ?>
                            <div class='miniatura-entrada-anuncio'>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                        <?php }
                        if ($contador == 1 || $contador == 4 || $contador == 5) { ?>
                            <div class='miniatura-entrada-big insertar-miniatura-entrada' data-insertar-miniatura-entrada='<?php echo $entrada['imagen']; ?>'>
                            </div>
                        <?php }
                        if ($contador == 6 ||  $contador == 9) { ?>
                            <div class='miniatura-entrada-medium insertar-miniatura-entrada' data-insertar-miniatura-entrada='<?php echo $entrada['imagen']; ?>'>
                            </div>
                        <?php }
                        if ($contador == 3 || $contador == 8) { ?>
                            <div class='miniatura-entrada-small insertar-miniatura-entrada' data-insertar-miniatura-entrada='<?php echo $entrada['imagen']; ?>'>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php $contador++;
                    } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="botonSiguienteAnterior">
                    <button class="secondary-btn">Anterior</button><button class="secondary-btn">Siguiente</button>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

[image: La imágen]

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías añadir tu html para ver como lo tienes hecho?

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes darle la altura que necesitas a través del **css** aprovechando algunas de las clases ya existentes en tu código o creando una concreta para esta necesidad de tu código. En este caso yo he optado por la primera opción como verás en el código **css*** que comparto abajo, siempre entendiendo que el contenedor de cada una de esas imágenes ya tiene un alto definido. He añadido tres supuestos, en el primero se da el alto a las imágenes que cargan dentro del **div**, y en el segundo, suponiendo que cargues dichas imágenes como un **background**, diciéndole que ocupe todo el espacio disponible con la propiedad **background-size: cover**. Por último, si estás haciendo tu proyecto usando flexbox, en ese caso lo que debe contener es la propiedad **strech** la clase **css** del contenedor.

```css
.contenedor-miniaturas .insertar-miniatura-entrada img {
min-height:100%; /*o en su defecto el número de píxeles que concreto que se necesite*/
}
/*o en caso de que se trate de un background*/
.contenedor-miniaturas .insertar-miniatura-entrada {
background-size: cover;
}
/*en caso de utilizar flexbox*/
.contenedor-miniaturas {align-items: stretch}
```

```html
<section id="blog">
    <?php
    $entrada = new Entrada();
    $entrada->get();
    $datos = $entrada->get_rows();
    $tamañoCompleto = count($datos);
    $datos = array_reverse($datos);
    $contador = 1;
    if ($datos) { ?>
        <div class="contenedor-blog">
            <?php if (!isset($_GET['entrada'])) { ?>
                <!--  Contenedor miniaturas -->
                <div class="contenedor-miniaturas">
                    <?php foreach ($datos as $key => $entrada) {
                        if ($contador == 2 || $contador == 7) { ?>
                            <div class='miniatura-entrada-anuncio'>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                        <?php }
                        if ($contador == 1 || $contador == 4 || $contador == 5) { ?>
                            <div class='miniatura-entrada-big insertar-miniatura-entrada' data-insertar-miniatura-entrada='<?php echo $entrada['imagen']; ?>'>
                            </div>
                        <?php }
                        if ($contador == 6 ||  $contador == 9) { ?>
                            <div class='miniatura-entrada-medium insertar-miniatura-entrada' data-insertar-miniatura-entrada='<?php echo $entrada['imagen']; ?>'>
                            </div>
                        <?php }
                        if ($contador == 3 || $contador == 8) { ?>
                            <div class='miniatura-entrada-small insertar-miniatura-entrada' data-insertar-miniatura-entrada='<?php echo $entrada['imagen']; ?>'>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php $contador++;
                    } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="botonSiguienteAnterior">
                    <button class="secondary-btn">Anterior</button><button class="secondary-btn">Siguiente</button>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

En cualquier caso, si compartes el css que estás aplicando será  más fácil dar una solución más detallada y ajustada a las necesidades de tu proyecto